# Preprocessing Target for Survival Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python, survival, data-preprocessing

I am wondering if it is recommendable to preprocess the target for Survival Analysis, regression. Lets say the target is a time-to-event, for example the duration in days for process tasks. 
I plot a histogram for this with the quantiles: [image: histogram with the quantiles]

As you can see, because of some outliers the last quantil is bigger than 75% of all the other values. I am not sure, if there would be any negative effects, when preprocessing the target? 
My proposals would be to use one of these three methods:
1) log on duration to avoid skewness
2) remove outliers (I thought about all values over 900 days)
3) Box Cox Transform

I already tried the second method:

[image: log duration]

I would be happy about some suggestion on your experiences, if one of this methods would be a good way or if its better to don't manipulate the target values? Or maybe some other proposals? Thank you!

Comment: Non need for transformation. Non-parametric (Cox) or semi-parametric methods for baseline hazard estimation will approximate the distribution of the survival times appropriately (albeit with high uncertainty towards the end of the follow up). Do not remove the observations, instead Introduce administrative censoring (for example at 1000 (or 900) days), which can make estimation more robust without completely omitting the information of the observations with t > 1000.

Comment: @adibender thanks for your answer. It's good to know, that I don't need transformation here. I don't get, what you mean with "administrave censoring", only thing I found with this keyword was "Day X" or "End of the Study". Do you have any information, for what I can search for better?

Comment: you set the time of event for observations with t > 1000 to t = 1000 and status variable to status = 0, thus you introduce censoring at t = 1000. Thereby you still use information of observations with t > 1000 to estimate hazard/survival probability until t <= 1000